# Appending spaces to the rest of fixed length record in UNIX Script

Tags: linux, shell-script, text-formatting

I have the data for about 40 characters in the record of 250 length(FIXED). But I want to append the remaining 250-40=210 characters with SPACES. How do we do in UNIX Script?

Comment: What do you mean with an "UNIX script"? A shell script? Something else? Is it some tool you already have and are modifying, or are you just looking for a way to do this in whatever tool is useful? Where's the data? In a file? In a variable in a shell script? What else is there, or is it just that one record?

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`:

```bsh
awk '{ printf "%-250s\n", $0 }' infile >outfile
```

The formatting string `%-250s` used with `printf` here formats the argument, `$0` (the current line), as a string of length 250 characters.  Within those 250 characters, the original line will be left-aligned, and the bit not taken up by the input line is filled out with spaces to fill the 250 positions.

If an input line is more than 250 characters long, then this is reproduced unmodified in the output.  To chop too-long lines off at 250 characters, use `substr($0,1,250)` in place of `$0` in the code above.

Comment: I'm writing header , then detail and then trailer. It is appending spaces to header but not to trailer record. Is there any rule that we should not use awk command continuously OR we need to initialize it before using it second time in the same script?

Comment: @ramkumar [update your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/688401/edit) with an example of what you're doing, and then we can easily see what you mean

Comment: @ramkumar The `awk` command I gave would affect all lines in the given input file. It makes no difference between headers, body, or footer lines. I can't see how you are using my command, but it sounds like you're doing it in a loop (?). I was assuming you had a data file that you wanted to adjust once and for all. If that is not the case, then please update your question and give representative samples of data and a description of what you're doing.

Comment: You can also use `printf "%-250.250s\n"` to pad *and truncate* to 250 characters (bytes in some implementations)